# How to "rm -rf" with excluding files and folders with the "find -o" command

Tags: linux, bash, find, rm

I'm trying to use the `find` command, but still can't figure out how to pipe the `find ...` to `rm -rf`

Here is the directory tree for testing:

```
/path/to/directory
/path/to/directory/file1_or_dir1_to_exclude
/path/to/directory/file2_or_dir2_to_exclude
/path/to/directory/.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude
/path/to/directory/.hidden_file2_or_dir2_to_exclude

/path/to/directory/many_other_files
/path/to/directory/many_other_directories
```

Here is the command for removing the whole directory:

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

But how to `rm -rf` while excluding files and folders?

Here is the `man` help for reference:

```
man find

-prune True;  if  the  file is a directory, do not descend into it.  If
      -depth is given, then -prune has no effect.  Because -delete im‐
      plies  -depth,  you  cannot  usefully use -prune and -delete to‐
      gether.
        For example, to skip the directory `src/emacs' and  all  files
      and directories under it, and print the names of the other files
      found, do something like this:
                find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

What's the `-o` in this `find` command? Does it mean "or"? I can't find the meaning of `-o` in the man page.

```
mkdir -p /path/to/directory

mkdir -p /path/to/directory/file1_or_dir1_to_exclude
mkdir -p /path/to/directory/file2_or_dir2_to_exclude

mkdir -p /path/to/directory/.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude
mkdir -p /path/to/directory/.hidden_file2_or_dir2_to_exclude

mkdir -p /path/to/directory/many_other_files
mkdir -p /path/to/directory/many_other_directories
```

I have tried to use this `find` command to exclude the `.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude` and then pipe it to `rm`, but this command does not work as expected.

```
cd /path/to/directory
find . -path ./.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude -prune -o -print | xargs -0 -I {} rm -rf {}
```

Comment: It means "or". Recall that expression stops evaluating when or is true so the rest is not done. Debug the expression you want with print, then change to rm.

Comment: Hi stack, thanks for your help. Now I have understand the meaning of "-o" in the find comand, but still don't know how to pipe it to the "rm -rf". I have updated the question to include the testing script, can you help to check it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `rm -rf` is to recursively remove everything in a directory tree.

The way to avoid recursively removing everything inside a directory is to get `find` to enumerate exactly the files you want to remove, and nothing else (and then of course you don't need `rm` at all; `find` knows how to remove files, too).

```sh
find . -depth -path './.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude/*' -o -delete
```

Using `-delete`  turns on the `-depth` option, which disables the availability of `-prune`; but just say "delete if not in this tree" instead. And indeed, as you seem to have discovered already, `-o` stands for "or".

The reason `-delete` enables `-depth` should be obvious; you can't traverse the files inside a directory after you have deleted it.

As an aside, you need to use `-print0` if you use `xargs -0`. (This facility is a GNU extension, and generally not available on POSIX.)

Comment: This command does not work, it says: find: The -delete action automatically turns on -depth, but -prune does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - updated now, but probably try it with `-print` instead of `-delete` first!

Comment: I have tried the latest command but it does not exclude the folder: find . -depth -path './.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude/*' -o -delete

Comment: Thanks tripleee! Thanks for your help, the "-print0" works in this command: find . -path ./.hidden_file1_or_dir1_to_exclude -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -rf {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate files from directories to exclude:

```
find . -mindepth 1\
       \( -path ./dir_to_exclude -o\
          -path ./.hidden_dir_to_exclude \) -type d -prune\
       -o\
     ! \( -path ./file_to_exclude -o\
          -path ./.hidden_file_to_exclude \)\
        -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

You can remove the `echo` once tested.